# How to create a list of totals for durations?

Tags: python, time, recursion, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.x

I want to calculate a bonus based on the two consecutive months where sales where the most. So I can iterate a total for every two consecutive months to find the Max value ie get

`value = Max[total_between_firstdayMonth1_and_lastDayMonth2, total_between_firstdayMonth2_and_lastDayMonth3, ... , total_between_firstdaySecondToLastMonth_andlastDayLastMonth]`

So I might need a list of pairs of datetime objects or something similar.

```
start= model.Order.order('created').get().created # get the oldest order
end = model.Order.order('-created').get().created # get the newest order
```

So inbetween start and end I must partition the time in overlapping pairs of consecutive 2 months eg. if first order was in december 2008 and the last order was in november 2011 then the list from where to pick the max should be `[total_december2008 + total_january2009, total_january2009 + total_february2009, ... , total_october2011 + total_november2011]`

But then how do I get the last day of the second month if I know the start like above? How can I create the list of times and totals?

I might not be able to create the list of totals right away but if I can create the list of starts and ends then I can call a helper function we can assume eg.

`total(start_datetime, end_datetime)`

Thanks for any help

### Update

I think I found how to calculate the time for an example interval where the timeline is from any date to last day next month:

```
>>> d = date(2007,12,18)
>>> print d
2007-12-18
>>> d + relativedelta(months=2) - timedelta(days=d.day)
datetime.date(2008, 1, 31)
```

### Update 2

I can calculate upto the first level the first duration. Now I only have to generalize it to loop through all the durations and check which was the highest level:

```
def level(self):
    startdate = model.Order.all().filter('status =', 'PAID').filter('distributor_id =' , self._key.id()).get().created.date()
    last_day_nextmonth =startdate + relativedelta(months=2) - timedelta(days=1)
    if self.personal_silver(startdate, last_day_nextmonth) + self.non_manager_silver(startdate, last_day_nextmonth) < 25:
        maxlevel = _('New distributor')
    elif self.personal_silver(startdate, last_day_nextmonth) + self.non_manager_silver(startdate, last_day_nextmonth)   > 25:
        maxlevel = _('Assistant Teamleader')
    return maxlevel
```

### Update 3

Closer to what I mean is taking the max of some function values from beginning up to now. Basecase can be that last day next month is is the future and the helper function can be recursive but I didn't have time or help to make it recursive to it only works for the first 2 periods now ie 4 months from start:

```
def level(self):
    startdate = model.Order.all().filter('status =', 'PAID'
            ).filter('distributor_id =',
                     self._key.id()).get().created.date()
    last_day_nextmonth = startdate + relativedelta(months=2) \
        - timedelta(days=1)
    total = self.personal_silver(startdate, last_day_nextmonth) + self.non_manager_silver(startdate, last_day_nextmonth)
    if total >= 125:
        level = 5
    elif total >= 75:
        level = 4
    elif total >= 25:
        level = 3
    elif total >= 2:
        level = 2
    else:
        level = 1
    return self.levelHelp(level, last_day_nextmonth + timedelta(days=1))

def levelHelp(self, level, startdate):
    #if startdate in future return level
    last_day_nextmonth = startdate + relativedelta(months=2) \
        - timedelta(days=1)
    total = self.personal_silver(startdate, last_day_nextmonth) + self.non_manager_silver(startdate, last_day_nextmonth)
    if total >= 125:
        newlevel = 5
    elif total >= 75:
        newlevel = 4
    elif total >= 25:
        newlevel = 3
    elif total >= 2:
        newlevel = 2
    else:
        newlevel = 1
    return level if level > newlevel else newlevel
```

### Update 4

I added the recursion where base case is that next step is in the future, if so it will return the max level:

```
def level(self):
    startdate = model.Order.all().filter('status =', 'PAID'
            ).filter('distributor_id =',
                     self._key.id()).get().created.date()
    last_day_nextmonth = startdate + relativedelta(months=2) \
        - timedelta(days=1)
    total = self.personal_silver(startdate, last_day_nextmonth) + self.non_manager_silver(startdate, last_day_nextmonth)
    if total >= 125:
        level = 5
    elif total >= 75:
        level = 4
    elif total >= 25:
        level = 3
    elif total >= 2:
        level = 2
    else:
        level = 1
    return self.levelHelp(level, last_day_nextmonth + timedelta(days=1))

def levelHelp(self, level, startdate):

    last_day_nextmonth = startdate + relativedelta(months=2) \
        - timedelta(days=1)
    total = self.personal_silver(startdate, last_day_nextmonth) + self.non_manager_silver(startdate, last_day_nextmonth)
    if total >= 125:
        newlevel = 5
    elif total >= 75:
        newlevel = 4
    elif total >= 25:
        newlevel = 3
    elif total >= 2:
        newlevel = 2
    else:
        newlevel = 1

    maxlevel = level if level > newlevel else newlevel

    nextstart = last_day_nextmonth + timedelta(days=1)
    now = datetime.now().date()
    if nextstart > now: #next start in is the future
        return maxlevel
    else: return self.levelHelp(maxlevel, nextstart)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a fine job for *functional approach*. At the end there is a full working example, but I just want to emphasize the elegance and simplicity of the core function, written in FP style:

```
def find_best_two_months(orders):
  first  = lambda x: x[0]
  second = lambda x: x[1]

  orders_by_year_and_month = [ 
    ("%04d-%02d" % (date.year, date.month), amount) 
    for date, amount in orders]

  sorted_orders = sorted(orders_by_year_and_month, key=first)

  totals_by_month = [ 
    (ym, sum(map(second, groupped_orders))) 
    for ym, groupped_orders in groupby(sorted_orders, key=first)]

  totals_two_months = [ 
    ( "%s - %s" % (m1[0], m2[0]), m1[1]+m2[1] ) 
    for m1, m2 in zip(totals_by_month, totals_by_month[1:]) ]

  return max(totals_two_months, key=second)
```

---

Here is a full working example with comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from random import randint
from datetime import date, timedelta
from itertools import groupby

""" finding best two months the functional way """

def find_best_two_months(orders):
  """
  Expect a list of tuples of form (date_of_order, amount):

  [ (date1, amount1), (date2, amount2), ...]
  """

  " helper functions for extracting first or second from tuple "
  first  = lambda x: x[0]
  second = lambda x: x[1]

  " converts [(date, amount)] -> [(YYYY-MM, amount)] "
  orders_by_year_and_month = [ ("%04d-%02d" % (date.year, date.month), amount) for date, amount in orders]

  " Sorts by YYYY-MM. This step can be omitted if orders were already sorted by date"
  sorted_orders = sorted(orders_by_year_and_month, key=first)

  " Compresses orders from the same month, so ve get [(YYYY-MM), total_amount_of_orders]"
  totals_by_month = [ (ym, sum(map(lambda x:x[1], groupped_orders))) 
    for ym, groupped_orders in groupby(sorted_orders, key=first)]

  " Zips orders to two month periods"
  totals_two_months = [ ("%s - %s" % (m1[0], m2[0]), m1[1]+m2[1]) for m1, m2 in zip(totals_by_month, totals_by_month[1:]) ]

  " Returns two-month period with maximum total amount. If there were many periods with max amount, only the first is returned "
  return max(totals_two_months, key=second)

""" 
this code is for generating random list of orders 
and is not a part of the solution 
"""
MIN_AMOUNT=70
MAX_AMOUNT=500
MAX_DAY_SPREAD=5

def gen_order(last_date):
  """ returns (order_date, amount) """
  days = timedelta()
  return (
      last_date+timedelta(days=randint(0, MAX_DAY_SPREAD)),  # new date
      randint(MIN_AMOUNT, MAX_AMOUNT)) # amount

def gen_orders(total, start_date):
  orders = []
  last_date = start_date
  for i in range(total):
    order = gen_order(last_date)
    orders.append(order)
    last_date = order[0]
  return orders

if __name__ == "__main__":
  orders = gen_orders(300, date(2010,1,1)) 
  print find_best_two_months(orders)
```